# Правила вывода типа для ключевого слова auto

Tags: c++, c++11

Как определяется тип инициализируемой переменной при использовании ключевого слова `auto`?

В каких случаях переменная окажется константной, ссылкой, указателем, или всё это в различных комбинациях?

Как повлияют на эти правила дополнительные указания, типа `const auto`, `auto&`, `const auto&` (и ещё наверное аналогичные с указателями, может даже с двойными указателями, и с `&&`)?

Comment: Ссылки никогда не выводятся.

Comment: По моему(если не брать в счет учебники) в интернете полно информации об этом. Выводится точный тип  правого операнда.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Правила вывода очень похожи на правила для функций вроде `template <typename T> void foo(T)`.

`[const] [volatile] auto` - никогда не будет ссылкой, никакие cv-квалификаторы (`const`, `volatile`) автоматически не добавляются.

Особый случай - если такую переменную инициализировать `= {a,b,c}` - то тип будет `[const] [volatile] std::initializer_list<T>`.

`[const] [volatile] auto &` - cv-квалификаторы добавляются автоматически (кроме случая, когда его инициализируют rvalue - тогда без указания `const` будет ошибка).

```
int a = 1;
const int b = 1;
auto &x = a; // int &x
auto &y = b; // const int &y
auto &z = 1; // Ошибка, хотя `const int &z = 1` скомпилировалось бы.
const auto &w = 1; // const int &w
```

`[const] [volatile] auto &&` - если указан хотя бы один cv-квалификатор, то работает по аналогии с `auto &`, но для rvalue.

Если cv-квалификаторы не указаны, то работает как forwarding ссылка:

```
MyClass a = 1;
const MyClass b = 1;
auto &&x = a; // MyClass &x
auto &&x = b; // const MyClass &x
auto &&x = MyClass(); // MyClass &&x
auto &&x = (const MyClass) MyClass(); // const MyClass &&x
```

`[const] [volatile] auto &&`, так же как и `auto`, умеет работать с `initializer_list`:

```
auto &&x = {1,2,3}; // std::initializer_list<int> &&
```

---

Во всех случаях выше, если переменную инициализировать `{a}` (без `=`), то `auto` ведет себя так же, как если бы инициализатор был `= a`. В фигурных скобках должен быть только один элемент.

---

`auto` может упоминаться в более сложных конструкциях: можно делать указатели на `auto`, указатели-на-члены, и ссылки на них. Разрешаются указатели на указатели, указатели на функции, и т.д. Но массивы с `auto` почему-то нельзя делать.

Если сделать указатель на `auto`, то cv-квалификаторы добавляются автоматически:

```
const int x = 1;
auto *y = &x; // const int *y
```

---

Есть еще `decltype(auto)`. Он похож на `auto`, но на него нельзя формировать ссылки и указатели, и нельзя указывать cv-квалификаторы.

Он использует те же правила вывода, что и `decltype`.

Он особенно хорошо подходит для написания оберток для функций:

```
decltype(auto) foo(бла бла)
{
    return bar(бла бла);
}
```

Здесь возвращаемый тип `bar` копируется в `foo`, даже если это ссылка.

Comment: Но массивы с auto нельзя делать, потому что вы сами сказали, что .auto - никогда не будет ссылкой,

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Не совсем понял. Скажем, `auto x[3] = {1,2,3};` - не работает, но здесь `auto` и не должен быть ссылкой.

Comment: если с правой стороны список инициализации, то  какой тип вывести, как узнать, что вы имеете ввиду массив, а не другую сущность? Я имел ввиду, что `int a[3] = {1,2,3};  auto x = a; `  не сработает. Это будет работать, если слева ссылька., например так: `decltype((a)) x = a;`

Comment: @ARHovsepyan `int a[3]; auto &b = a;` тоже работает, но `auto (&b)[3] = a;` почему-то нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int n = 5;
auto m = n;  // int    
const int& p = n;
auto q = p;   //int
const std::vector<int> v(1);
auto a = v[0];          //  int 
decltype(a) d ;          // int, тип сущности, именованной как d 
decltype(v[0]) b = 1;   //  const int& (возвращаемое значение
                        // std::vector<int>::operator[](size_type) const)    
decltype((a)) ref = a;  // int&, так как (a) является lvalue
auto value = ref;       //int
++ref;   // ошибка
++value; //правильно
```