# auto со вложенными приватными классами

Tags: c++, классы, вложенные-классы

Сегодня писал класс для работы с памятью и мне потребовалось использовать в нём другой вложенный класс. В главном классе был метод который возвращает объект этого вложенного класса:

```
class Main
{
private:
    class Inner
    {
        
    };
public:
    Inner foo()
    { return {}; }
};
```

Потом я сделал так:

```
Main m;
auto a = m.foo();
```

И это сработало. Но на прямую создать такой объект нельзя, т. к. вложенный класс - приватный:

```
Main::Inner a; //ошибка
```

Если честно я немного в замешательстве и меня интересует, дефект это или так и было задумано ( просто я до этого момента нигде не видел такого ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что public/private контролирует только имена и только на этапе компиляции. А auto в данном случае как бы не попадает под это правило, так как компилятор грубо говоря делает typedef. А typedef может "поменять доступность" функции.

Почему так? видимо потому, что auto в большинстве случаев копирует поведение с [шаблонных вещей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1075274/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-auto),  а там (в шаблонной магии) бывает много случаев, когда тип с одной стороны скрыт, а с другой виден.

Вот например, такой пример (он есть по ссылке ниже):

```
template <typename T>
void fun(T t) {}

int main() {
    Foo f;
    fun(f.Baz());         // ok
}
```

Тип f.Baz() может быть совсем неизвестен функции fun, но это работает.

Ещё раз. private/public действует на имена, но не на сами типы, хотя в головах большинства людей, это одно и тоже. а auto как бы дает ещё одно имя.

Такой же вопрос на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532784/why-can-i-use-auto-on-a-private-type)

Answer (score 1):

Да, это действительно один из дефектов механизма контроля доступа в С++. Однако использование `auto` тут никакой роли не играет. На строке `auto a = m.foo();` просто вызывается `public` функция без каких-либо ограничений доступа. Проблемным местом на самом деле является использование идентификатора с private доступом при объявлении чего-то c public доступом. На строке `public: Inner foo()` контроль доступа это разрешает, хотя по сути тут происходит вываливание приватной начинки класса наружу и ранее заданный модификатор доступа для `Inner` становится бесполезен.

В более толковых языках, например в c# или kotlin, контроль доступа реализован более ответственно, и попытки использовать идентификатор с более ограниченным доступом при объявлении чего-то с более широким доступом приведут к ошибке сборки. В С++ предлагали ввести подобное улучшение, однако это бы поломало обратную совместимость (как и большинство дельных предложений). Пока можно воспользоваться рекомендацией из Misra C++: размещать объявления в классе строго в порядке `public`, `protected`, `private`. При таком подходе в секциях с более широким доступом имена с более ограниченным доступом использоваться не могут, так как они будут объявлены позднее:

```
class Main
{
public:
    Inner foo() // error: 'Inner' does not name a type
    {
        return {};
    }
private:
    class Inner
    {
        
    };
};
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRABWUlfQAZPLUwAcs4ARpjEIADspAAOqEKE5rR2ji7uMXEJdL7%2BQU6h4VHGmKaJDATMxATJzq4eRSV0ZRUE2YEhYZFG5ZXVqXXdLX5teR0RAJRGqA7EyBxSyKpCQgDUALLMfpoyAIKaEfo70Q7BrHjIIFvby9fLAJK0/sTLNKgQY5c3y3sHV583xJgCNNaF99nsACKaADMP0%2BEMu0WIeAAbswCBwPjcFswlncHmFMddvoS/iT4TDLuSflIJqxpG55K5ZPJUNIbAYDMshFMZpgvtooZx5ARpHIxhMANYgKFQgB0MoViqVADYVNJuIzRSzpPIhCAZKQRcyJnBYEg0E5onh2GQKBALVabSBgJxXXxrejiHqIMEtaRgn4KgBPaRC0gWpxWAgAeVorBDzNIWCcamA7D9%2BABJWRmD1icw4mKDnRofkfnRdMTp2CxGDdiwfoISKcpYm/EYLHTPD4dAIwjEkkTSk4KlTKA5ehUeGCesgE1Q0TMdDzuswJiXrggXl6rhHXlauXyyli8Q3O%2BPGQ3B/a4RH9Q3TR69hqynvpQG15Gt66zXPd4/QyHh0nATNy0yzFwtL0pqiaslI4gABzKgAtMq3DLMAyDIMsrqypwywQLghAkPygqkMsdiWtaYSkSBFETrowpauKpBSjK8pKpxMqqpWGqkEycikHBur6oazGkKaiAgFMBBHAQ5CUA61Hfpg%2BBEN%2B7ZMGwHDdu2/YSH6ADutbRK2apSAy/F%2BnB0bFnJyyoFQyyIShaEYVhOGcHhBGUY6NE6IKYxMcakrSnKXFceZfECdqUgiQaRpilBUjaDBgnCWJIWkDmXqJCA3BAA%3D%3D)